# Generic class with dependent generic types, cannot specialize?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently working with the following types:

```
// A Field whose values are of type V.
interface Field<V> {
    public V getValue();
}

// A Field whose values are of type V and that has a LabelProvider for those values.
interface LabelField<V> extends Field<V> {
    public LabelProvider<V> getLabelProvider();
}
```

These come from a library and I cannot change them. This is probably not relevant, but a LabelProvider is basically a class that converts values of type V to Strings.

Now I want to create a class that provides an interface similar to this:

```
// A Wrapper class for Fields of values V
interface IWrapper<V, F extends Field<V>> {
    public F getField();
    public V getValue();
    public String getLabel();
}
```

The class will wrap a Field, and let its users retrieve the value from the field, but also provide other functionalities, including retrieving the label. Here's what I have:

```
public class Wrapper<V, F extends Field<V>> {

    private F field;
    private LabelProvider<V> labelProvider; // Converts from V to String

    // Since we have no guarantee that F has a LabelProvider, one is explicitely supplied.
    public Wrapper(F field, LabelProvider<V> labelProvider) {
        this.field = field;
        this.labelProvider = labelProvider;
    }

    private String getLabel() {
        return labelProvider.getLabel(field.getValue());
    }

    public F getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return field.getValue();
    }
}
```

1. No problem until this point, although I'm not sure whether I need these two generic types. Ideally I would have prefered to just have Wrapper> and be able to access both F and V. I think that this is not possible, and that the above is the correct way to do this ?
2. Now here's the real issue.

I want to have a more specific constructor for the LabelField type, which would look like this:

```
public Wrapper(LabelField<V> labelField) {
    // Use the field's own label provider
    this(labelField, labelField.getLabelProvider());
}
```

In this case the labelprovider can be extracted from the field. But the compiler doesn't like this and I get the following error:

```
The constructor Wrapper<V,F>(LabelField<V>, LabelProvider<V>) is undefined
```

Even though this method, which uses the same types, compiles :

```
public static <X> void test(LabelField<X> lf) {
    LabelProvider<X> lp = lf.getLabelProvider();
    new Wrapper<X, LabelField<X>>(lf, lp);
}
```

Why doesn't the second constructor compile ?

Here's a SSCE : http://pastebin.com/UqLJhJA7

Comment: Why aren't you just wrapping labelfields, which are already fields themselves?

Comment: I must support other kinds of fields which are not labelfields.

Comment: Also: I've already solved the business problem, but I'm interested in understanding how and why this doesn't type-check anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F` can be any type that extends `Field<V>`, and that type is not necessarly a `LabelField`.

For example, if you create a class `FooField` that implements `Field<Object>`, and use `Wrapper<Object, FooField>`, the `LabelField` constructor will not match.

You can simplify your wrapper this way (and this also answers your first point):

```
public class Wrapper<V> {

    private Field<V> field;

    private LabelProvider<V> labelProvider; // Converts from V to String

    // Since we have no guarantee that F has a LabelProvider, one is explicitely
    // supplied.
    public Wrapper(Field<V> field, LabelProvider<V> labelProvider) {
        this.field = field;
        this.labelProvider = labelProvider;
    }

    public Wrapper(LabelField<V> labelField) {
        // Use the field's own label provider
        this(labelField, labelField.getLabelProvider());
    }

    private String getLabel() {
        return this.labelProvider.getLabel(this.field.getValue());
    }

    public Field<V> getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.field.getValue();
    }
}
```

This uses "regular" polymorphism instead of generics for `field`.

Comment: This is what I actually implemented yes, but we lose the genericity in the Field type (thus we'll need to cast when calling getField()). In your opinion there's no way to do better ?

Comment: @ARRG in that case you could specialize by subclassing Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You mixed generics and inheritance.

You should parametrize only with `V`:

```
public class Wrapper<V>
```

and write below

```
Field<V>
```

in all places you would write

```
F
```